# How to assign returned result to variable when using "Except" in ms msql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 temporary table that I am comparing. I would like to have a variable to hold either the count of differences between these 2 tables or just varchar of differences that comes from except.

I have below query so far

```
Declare @comparison AS NVARCHAR(2000);
SET @comparison=(select * from #dboPerson1
                            except
                 select * from #dboPerson2);
Select @comparison
```

I get following error:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

I tried adding count(*)  before select and the comparison variable becomes the number of records that are different between two temporary tables.

But it was printing select * except result and as well as count.

I would like to assign the differences two variable without showing it on console unless I chose to select the variable name.

Hope it makes sense. I am using sql server 2012 btw.

Thanks.

Comment: The reason for the error is a varchar will not hold multiple fields (i.e. SELECT *).  If you want to hold all the differences you need a table variable with all the fields you are selecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to have a variable to hold either the count of differences [...]

```
DECLARE @comparison INT;
SET @comparison=
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM (select * from #dboPerson1 except select * from #dboPerson2) x
);
```

Comment: one quick question what is that x after the subquery. Without it I would get syntax error.

Comment: It's an alias for `(select * from #dboPerson1 except select * from #dboPerson2)` subquery. Without this alias you get that error. See section [Arguments > AS table_alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

Comment: Oh I see. So it can be anything you want it to be. Is it similar to alias using AS? so like AS myalias same as just having myalias in this case?

Comment: Yes. The `AS` keyword is optional.